# Intermediate Layer loss calculation for conditional Computation

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, mlp

I want to create an MLP based custom CNN model (multi-scaled) consists of several parallel small networks (capsules). These simple small networks are instantiated as a custom layer (conv2d->Flatten->Dense) for each convolution scale i.e. 3x3, 5x5. The purpose of these capsule networks is to generate intermediate loss consciousness to reduce overall global loss using the CNN model. I have written some sketchy codes but I'm not able to write the correct code for computing local loss using these capsules. Here's the code:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer

class capsule(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self):
     super(capsule, self).__init__()
     self.loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
     self.Flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
     self.conv2D = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3,3,(1,1),padding='same', activation='relu',name="LocalLoss3x3")
     self.classifier = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax', name='capsule3Output')

 def call(self, inputs):
    x=self.conv2D(inputs)
    x=self.Flatten(x)
    x=self.classifier(x)
    pred=self(x_train)
    loss=self.loss_fn(pred,y_train)
    #self.add_loss(self.rate * tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(inputs)))
    return loss, x

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)=  mnist.load_data()
from tensorflow.keras import layers
class SparseMLP(tf.keras.models.Model):

def __init__(self, output_dim):
  super(SparseMLP, self).__init__()
  self.dense_1 = layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.relu)
  self.capsule = capsule()
  self.dense_2 = layers.Dense(output_dim)

def call(self, inputs):
  x = self.dense_1(inputs)
  loss,x = self.capsule(inputs)
  return self.dense_2(x)


mlp = SparseMLP(10)
#x_train=x_train.reshape(-1,28,28,1)
y = mlp(x_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

To include a loss within a layer , you can use `add_loss` function of `tf.keras.layers.Layer` class. This fucntion takes a loss value and adds it up to the global loss function define in compile function.

> you can call self.add_loss(loss_value) from inside the call method of a custom
> layer.Losses added in this way get added to the "main" loss during training
> (the one passed to compile()).

So to make ur model consider the losses from intermediate layer , you should uncomment the `add_loss` fn , and then train the model in usual way that you train.
Please mind that it is totally fine to not declare a "main" loss in the compile function as there already is a loss that ur defining in your layer class.

> Note that when you pass losses via add_loss(), it becomes possible to call compile() without a loss function, since the model already has a loss to minimize.

Please note that `call` function of SparseMLP model , should look like this:

```
       x = self.dense_1(inputs)
       # i dunno if u desire to do this, that is pass inputs in capsule 
       # instead of x.Currently the output from dense_1 is not used at all .
       # so keep in mind to make sure ur passing proper inputs to layers.
       # and u do not have to call loss here as it will tracked internally by 
       # keras.
       x = self.capsule(inputs)
       return self.dense_2(x)
```

So running your model like below should do the trick:

```
model.compile(loss = "define ur main loss is there is" , metrics = "define ur metrics")
model.fit(x = train_inst , y = train_targets)
```